# Not adding the same record checking loop

Tags: python, mysql

When adding a record to the database, how can I create a loop that will check if the record we have added exists before, check the next record if it is not, or add it if not?
I have a table in the database, there is a link structure from that table, I want this operation for that link column. Because a link can be pulled several times. There is an id in the link, I thought the id could be compared as well. The complete link is also comparable. I would be glad if you help.
I can add to this part, I am sharing the codes for an idea.

```py
            if (link == ""):
                control = "false"
            else:
                control = "true"

            if control == "true":
                mySql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO ad_l(id,count,clist_id,brand_model,ad,created_at,updated_at,status) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                val = (id, count, clist_id, brand_model, ad_link, link, created_at, updated_at, status)

                #cursor = scrap_db.cursor()
                cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query, val)  # cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query, tuple_of_tuples)

                scrap_db.commit()
                print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into *ad_l* table")
```

I added something like this but it didn't work.

```py
        if exists ("SELECT ad FROM ad_l WHERE AD = ad_link"):
            print('There is the same link, it is not added')
            pass
        else:
            print('New record being added')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO this would be better to solve on the DB level as `unique` column or `unique constraint` (unique over multiple columns).

The DBs are optimized to do this check for you which results in better performance.

In some cases you might use a DB trigger to automatically user insert or update based on whether the record already exists or not.

In python you can use SQLAlchemy but tbh it is not very begineer friendly.

---

If you need to do this from other perspective and check the DB for record before you initiate some link processing (scrapping), You were heading in right direction to check for existing record, but problem is, that `ad_link` in your query was meant to be a variable but you pass it as part of the query.

Change it to for example:

```
exists (f"SELECT ad FROM ad_l WHERE AD = {ad_link}")
```

add the `'` around `{ad_link}` if needed (I currently don't remember if its required)